# Null geometry for child feature

Tags: qgis, qfield

I'm using QField 1.9.6 and QGIS 3.18.2

In Qfield, I have a .shp layer called "photos". I also have a .shp layer called "trees". There is a 1:N relation between "trees" and "photos" (trees is the referencing or parent layer, photos is the referenced or child layer).

I can add a record directly to "photos" by digistising to the layer. I can also add a record to photos from the "trees" form, using a 'relation editor' widget. All works fine. Except I have recently noticed a change in behaviour. Previously, when adding a photo from the trees form, I was not prompted to 'plot' the location of the photo, i.e. I could add a record with no geometry, which suits my needs and workflow. For some time now, perhaps since QField 1.6 (?) I get prompted to plot the photo.

Is there a way to revert to the old behaviour, i.e. being allowed to have a null geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the child layer is a point layer, QField will ask for a geometry.
If the child layer is a simple table without geometries, QField will not ask for a geometry.

Change your child layer to a geopackage layer without geometry.

Comment: Noted. I liked the old behaviour because i could use the same layer for plotting photos directly, or adding them as child features with no geometry. But, so be it.

Comment: Adding a new functionality to create the point automatically with the current position would be a nice enhancement.